# Firebase realtime database location... NO NEXT BUTTON

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I was trying to get Realtime Database on Firebase, but it doesn't show me a 'NEXT' button when I'm trying to get the database location.

[image]

I was following online tutorials which are supposed to look like this:

[image]

and I have no idea why it happens like this to mine only

Comment: Have you tried to change the browser?

Comment: I just installed another browser after seeing your comment, and it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem for not displaying the "Next" button is related to your browser. The simplest solution to solving this kind of issue is to try to use the Firebase Console on another browser.